# How to add dynamic bookmark in QlikSense app

Tags: qliksense

I have a column in model with name [Year Week] and facing issue in creating dynamic bookmark in the app for that column. Data in the column is as below-

```
[Year Week]

2021-W20

2021-W21

2021-W22
```

I am now trying to add dynamic default filter so that my app always show data for the latest week and that is "2021-W22" for the above sample data. I am trying with these different ways (suggested in different community questions) with no luck-

```
=[Year Week] = MaxString({1}[Year Week])

=[Year Week] = MaxString([Year Week])

=Only({1}[Year Week] = MaxString([Year Week]))
```

**Note**: I also tried with Numeric value in the [Year Week] column like - 202120, 202121, 202122 but no success there as well.

Can some one please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [Total](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2021/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/define-aggregation-scope.htm) qualifier inside the calculation in order to get the total `MaxString` accross all values in the field

`=[Year Week] = MaxString(Total {1} [Year Week])`

Data without selections:

[image: No selection]

Filtered data:

[image: Applied calculated filter]